# Saving data in firebase with mapping

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I simply passing array to firebase to store data but it is not efficient way to query data from array. SO , I am planning to store data in mapping format. But not sure how to do that.

```
{
   "ClassDetails": 
   [
     {
       "Code": "CIS695",
       "Instructor": "Dr. Antony",
       "Location": "BB444",
       "Name": "Capstone project"
     }
   ],
   "PersonalDetials": [
     {
       "Email": "rshah2@murraystate.edu",
       "FName": "Ravi",
       "LName": "Shah",
       "Major": "MSIS"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Want to change in this format

```
{
   "ClassDetails": 
     "CIS695"{
       "Code": "CIS695",
       "Instructor": "Dr. Antony",
       "Location": "BB444",
       "Name": "Capstone project"
       }
       "CIS690"{
       "Code": "CIS690",
       "Instructor": "Dr. Smith",
       "Location": "BB444",
       "Name": "Project Management"
       }
   "PersonalDetials": 
     {
       "Email": "rshah2@murraystate.edu",
       "FName": "Ravi",
       "LName": "Shah",
       "Major": "MSIS"
     }
 }
```

Tried everything but couldn't find the proper solution.[Data structure in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOxdy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the structure of the `data` won't change, give this a try:

```js
const data = {
  "ClassDetails": [{
    "Code": "CIS695",
    "Instructor": "Dr. Antony",
    "Location": "BB444",
    "Name": "Capstone project"
  }],
  "PersonalDetials": [{
    "Email": "rshah2@murraystate.edu",
    "FName": "Ravi",
    "LName": "Shah",
    "Major": "MSIS"
  }]
};

const mappedData = { ...data
};
mappedData.ClassDetails = {};
for (const item in data.ClassDetails) {
  const itemToAdd = { ...data.ClassDetails[item]
  };
  mappedData.ClassDetails[itemToAdd.Code] = itemToAdd;
}
mappedData.PersonalDetials = mappedData.PersonalDetials[0];

console.log(mappedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  output = {};
  constructor() {
    let classDetails = {};
    this.input.ClassDetails.forEach(item => {
      classDetails[item.Code] = item;
    });
    this.output["ClassDetails"] = classDetails;
    this.output["PersonalDetials"] = this.input.PersonalDetials[0];
    console.log(this.output);
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjo6rv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**